# Can't figure out how to include a certain file in Rails/RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following code in `lib/test/company.rb`:

```
module Test
  class Company
    # irrelevant stuff
  end
end
```

In `spec/model/request.rb`, I've tried all of the following:

```
require "company"
require "lib/test/company"
require "lib/test/company.rb"
require Rails.root + "/lib/test/company.rb"
```

None of those works, at the class certainly isn't getting autoloaded. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your spec file:

```
require "test/company"
```

This is unnecessary if you'd like to autoload all modules/classes from lib. To do so, add to the config block in your application.rb file:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib )

  end
end
```

Addition:

You can then call `Test::Company` from the top-level namespace to access this class.

Comment: Hmm, neither suggestion worked. I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I restarted my server. I'm really baffled.

Comment: Try `Test::Company`. It looks like you're not calling it from within the `Test` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/test/company`.